# When does the soul enter the fetus?

Tags: halacha, pregnancy-birth

When during the pregnancy does the soul enter into the embryo or fetus?   At conception?  At how many weeks or months after conception or before birth?  Thank you

Comment: Note this time is not necessarily indicative of when it becomes prohibited to harm the fetus. That's a different issue.

Comment: Good point Double. I was going to leave that as a comment after my answer but forgot to.

Comment: Why is this tagged halacha?

Comment: @mevaqesh the fact that it was is either a proof to Double's suspicion, or the source of it.

Comment: @user6591 I suspected that it was the source. I was hoping that the OP might clarify, so that the distinction between the aggadic content of the answers, and the halakhic question of killing, could be further emphasised.

Comment: "For Judaism this is not a theological issue involving the ensoulment of the embryo, which is deemed one of the “secrets of God”, but a technical problem of whether the fetus has an independent legal status." -- Rabbi Apple, from Sydney. https://www.jwire.com.au/q-does-judaism-permit-abortions-ask-the-rabbi/

Answer (score 6):

This was a discussion between Antoninus and Rabi Yehuda HaNasi, found in Sanhedrin 91b.
The following is the quotation and translation from [sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.91b?lang=bi)

> וא"ל אנטונינוס לרבי נשמה מאימתי ניתנה באדם משעת פקידה או משעת יצירה א"ל  משעת יצירה א"ל אפשר חתיכה של בשר עומדת שלשה ימים בלא מלח ואינה מסרחת אלא משעת פקידה אמר רבי דבר זה למדני אנטונינוס ומקרא מסייעו שנאמר (איוב י, יב) ופקודתך שמרה רוחי
>
> Antoninus said to Rebbe
> "At what point is the soul given to a human? Is it from the moment of decree [that such a child will exist], or from the moment of formation"?
> He responded "from the moment of formation."
> He replied, "is it possible that a piece of meat can last for three days without salt, and yet not become rotten? Rather it must be from the moment of decree."
> Rebbe said: This thing that I learned from Antoninus, and there is a supporting verse: [Job 10] Your Providence has guarded my soul".

Here is Rashi's explanation of the two points of time under question.

> משעת יצירה - שנקרם כולו בבשר וגידין ועצמות:
>
> פקידה - משעה שהמלאך פוקד הטיפה ומביאה לפני המקום מה תהא עליה כדאמרינן בפרק כל היד במסכת נדה (דף טז:) מיד נזרקה בו נשמה וחיות:
>
> from the moment of formation — that it all is solidified with flesh, sinews, and bones
>
> decree — from the moment that the messenger pays attention to the drop and brings it before God, "what will be with it?" (as we said in tractate Niddah, chapter Kol Hayad), immediately a soul and life are thrust into it

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Feinstein writes in Igrot Moshe (Yoreh Deah, 3:138):

Ravina [who held the opinion that a child achieves Olam Haba from the time of conception] was the final arbiter of the halacha, and the halacha follows him. The definitive halacha is [therefore] that from the moment of conception, even in the case of a miscarriage afterwards, the child has a portion in Olam Haba, and will come back to life once there is techiat hameitim (revival of the dead), like a tzadik gamur [completely righteous person], untainted from any transgressions.